# Delete sub-document from array in array of sub documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's imagine a mongo collection of - let's say magazines. For some reason, we've ended up storing each issue of the magazine as a separate document. Each article is a subdocument inside an `Articles`-array, and the authors of each article is represented as a subdocument inside the `Writers`-array on the `Article`-subdocument. Only the name and email of the author is stored inside the article, but there is an `Writers`-array on the magazine level containing more information about each author.

```
{
   "Title": "The Magazine",
   "Articles": [
     {
       "Title": "Mongo Queries 101",
       "Summary": ".....",
       "Writers": [
         {
           "Name": "tom",
           "Email": "tom@example.com"
         },
         {
           "Name": "anna",
           "Email": "anna@example.com"
         }
        ]
     },
     {
       "Title": "Why not SQL instead?",
       "Summary": ".....",
       "Writers": [
         {
           "Name": "mike",
           "Email": "mike@example.com"
         },
         {
           "Name": "anna",
           "Email": "anna@example.com"
         }
        ]         
      }
   ],
  "Writers": [
     {
       "Name": "tom",
       "Email": "tom@example.com",
       "Web": "tom.example.com"
     },
     {
       "Name": "mike",
       "Email": "mike@example.com",
       "Web": "mike.example.com"
     },
     {
       "Name": "anna",
       "Email": "anna@example.com",
       "Web": "anna.example.com"
     }
   ]
}
```

**How can one author be completely removed from a magazines?**

Finding magazines where the unwanted author exist is quite easy. The problem is pulling the author out of all the sub documents.

MongoDB 3.6 introduces some new placeholder operators, `$[]` and `$[<identity>]`, and I suspect these could be used with either `$pull` or `$pullAll`, but so far, I haven't had any success.

Is it possible to do this in one go? Or at least no more than two? One query for removing the author from all the articles, and one for removing the biography from the magazine?

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample data set?

Comment: I've extended the samle doc a little bit. It should be enough. Try removing `{ "Name": "tom", "Email": "tom@example.com" }` from the doc.

Comment: You'll need to match both `Name` and `Email`. Alone, neither is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query.

```
db.col.update(
  {},
  {"$pull":{
    "Articles.$[].Writers":{"Name": "tom","Email": "tom@example.com"},
    "Writers":{"Name": "tom","Email": "tom@example.com"}
  }},
  {"multi":true}
);
```

Comment: I didn't expect that to work when I first read the answer, but after trying it out it did work. But how?? I would at least expected that the `Articles`and `Writers`-parts would have needed to be separated some how. Can you explain?

Comment: [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) operator takes document with key (array field) and value (query criteria) pair. The first key value part is to update the Writers array inside the Articles, which is key, using positional all operator with the value as query condition. The second key value part is to update Writers array outside of Articles, which is key, using query condition as value.

Comment: @Veeram Why do we need to go for `Articles.$[].Writers` instead of `Articles.$.Writers` here?

Comment: And BOOM! Now that the query is defined, it turns out that mlabs *still*  doesn't provide 3.6 databases. Not even in sandboxes. Same problem every time there is a new mongo version. Takes forever before mLabs provides support. Guess this is the year we'll have to drop them...

Comment: @Rahul Raj To be honest I just looked at `anna` record in two arrays and assumed that OP wanted to remove from all arrays. If Op wanted it to remove from single array I can update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: https://github.com/rahul-raj/MongoDB/blob/master/sample.txt
This query deletes the nested array alone from the data. Can you tell me whether my query is wrong and if wrong, how its different?
When I didnt specify match statement, this query was not working, hence added `and` conditional operator.

Comment: I wanted the author removed from all articles. If `.$.` only removes it from one array, which would it remove it from? The first with match?

Comment: Yeah the first one with the match. @RahulRaj Try `db.magazines.update(
{"Articles":{$elemMatch:{"Writers":{"Name":"tom", "Email":"tom@example.com"}}}},
{$pull: {"Articles.$.Writers":{"Name":"tom", "Email":"tom@example.com"}}},
{multi:true}
)`

Comment: Or better use `db.magazines.update(
{"Articles":{$elemMatch:{"Writers":{$elemMatch:{"Name":"tom", "Email":"tom@example.com"}}}}},
{$pull: {"Articles.$.Writers":{"Name":"tom", "Email":"tom@example.com"}}},
{multi:true}
)` which should work in all cases.

Comment: Thank you @Veeram for the clarification. Very interesting stuff :)